# Composer retornando erro de alocação de memoria

Tags: php, composer

Acabei de instalar o composer e estou tentando baixar alguns arquivos do sendgrid, entretanto ele está me retornando erro referente a memoria. Alguem sabe o que está causando isso e como resolver?

```
Installing sendgrid/php-http-client (3.1.0): Loading from cache
    proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory
    The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
    Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
The following exception is caused by a lack of memory or swap, or not having swap configured
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors for details

PHP Warning:  proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 959

Warning: proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 959

  [ErrorException]
  proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: Quais modulos estão instalados no php? Existe a extensao zip

Comment: Parece que era um problema referente a memoria, tive que ativar uma swap

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Problema resolvido, caso alguém possua esse mesmo erro corrigi desta forma:

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

fonte: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors

Comment: Tua resposta me ajudou a continuar com o `sudo composer update` que estava travando pelo mesmo motivo.

Answer (score 0):

A solução do @RonaldoM pode não funcionar caso a quantidade de memória necessária para rodar o script com composer seja maior que sua memória RAM + 1024 de swap.

Nesse caso aumente `count=1024` para outro valor, como por exemplo: `count=2048`.

Em especial para aqueles que estão tendo esse erro em uma **instância da AWS**, e não conseguem rodar de forma alguma um script, lembre que você pode aumentar / diminuir sem dificuldade temporariamente a memória RAM de sua instância fazendo o upgrade / downgrade do tipo de instância.

Para isso no menu Instances:

- selecione sua instância

clique em:

- actions > instance state > stop
- actions > instance settings > change instance type ([faça o upgrade para o próximo tipo com mais memória RAM](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/ec2/instance-types/))
- actions > instance state > start

Acesse a máquina e rode o composer, repita os passos acima para fazer o downgrade.